# How to Create play button to play Sound?

Tags: android, eclipse

i want to create a small play button that when the user tap the button it play an audio file
Can someone show me how to do this
I  also want to know how to create a pause button.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to make your own buttons. You can extend an existing View class(Button or View) and define and describe it programmatically, then use that class in your xml layout.

Or

Create your custom Pause and Play buttons in a graphical editor, like GIMP of PhotoShop. Note that you'll have to create assets for each state(normal, focused, pressed) and for various screen densities. Then just copy these into your drawable folders and define each button as a State List drawable. More info on that here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

If you're looking to play short sound files, I suggest SoundPool. It abstracts away all the low level stuff so that you can just focus on loading, playing and pausing sound files and worrying about making your button behave correctly. Have a look at that class here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html